# AngularJS: File upload

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload

I am a newbie of angularjs. My version is 1.6.4 using with nodeJS. I am following this tutorial for file upload [leon/angular-upload](https://github.com/leon/angular-upload). I did all the steps written here to make it work which are.

1) bower install --save angular-upload

2) Add module dependency "lr.upload" which i did

```
angular.module(__appName, ["ngMap", "multipleSelect", "lr.upload"]);
```

3) Add this code snippet in html page, so i did in my fileupload.html.

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-upload"
         upload-button
         url="/upload"
         on-success="onSuccess(response)"
         on-error="onError(response)">Upload</div>
```

4) And finally add script to html page.

```
<script src='bower_components/angular-upload/angular-upload.min.js'></script>
```

But i am still getting error:

> POST http://localhost:3000/upload 404 (Not Found)

My server.js is code is:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.redirect("app/index.html");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Tellworld web app listening on port 3000");
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Server.JS files that you should follow
https://github.com/leon/angular-upload/blob/master/example/server.js

You have to add :

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) { /*do your post processing here */ })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server will also need it route that receive request from the angular's route directive. In clear english you will need to declare a route pointing to upload in your server which may look like the code below

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body); //this is just to show the request body on your console
});
```